# How do Boolean and Conditional statements perform in Event Listeners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Can someone explain the logic here in the code. Why does it runs if variable *"started"* is already false and the condition on this event only runs if started is not false, why did it run if the condition itself inside the event listener defy the value of the variable *"started"*?

```
function nextSequence(){
 console.log("Hello World");
 }

var started = false;

$("body").on("keydown",function(){
   if(!started){
      nextSequence();
      started=true;
}
});
```

Comment: _"the condition on this event only runs if started is not false"_  you've got this bit wrong. The condition runs if `started` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/falsy). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT

Comment: Either => set started to `true` OR remove `!` from the if condition.

Comment: Why using `started` ? the value never change. this is really a bad code.

Comment: Okay guys I understand what you mean, so it's simply runs if the condition is **true** itself right? And the reason why it have "!" because goal is I need a way to keep track of whether if the game has started or not, so I only call nextSequence() on the first keydown.

Answer (score 1):

An `!` before a boolean inverts a boolean. So `true` becomes `false`. And `false` becomes `true`.

```js
console.log( false );
console.log( !false );
```

*PS: It can also casts another type than a boolean into a boolean and invert that value. But you don't need to know that for this example.*

Comment: there is also `!0` and `!7`

Comment: @MisterJojo If you are interested you can look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT  This page also has references to pages about what truthy and falsy values are. I do encourage people to read it, but it is beyond the scope of this question ;).

Comment: I understand it's inversion but what I don't understand is the condition of accepting boolean but I clearly see the light about it now so it's simply runs if the condition is true itself right?

Comment: `if(true){}` would execute whatever is in the `{}`. But you can also put some code that returns a value instead of the boolean `true`. It will solve that code first and check if it is truthy. So `if(!false){}` does the same as `if(true){}`.

Answer (score 1):

at least you can do :

```js
function nextSequence(){
  console.log('Hello World');
  $('body').off('keydown', nextSequence );
}

$('body').on('keydown', nextSequence );
```

or better (thanks to **Phil**)

```js
$('body').one('keydown', function() {
  console.log('Hello World');
})
```

or in pure JS:

```js
function firstSequence(){
  console.log('Hello World');
  document.removeEventListener('keydown',firstSequence)
}

document.addEventListener('keydown',firstSequence)
```

Comment: jQuery also has [`.one()`](https://api.jquery.com/one/) for single-run event handlers

Comment: @Phil, I forgot this one, I haven't been doing jQuery in years! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have negated your if condition

it should be

```
if(started){}
```